# How to keep S3 bucket permissions public

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket that currently holds several files within a folder, let's call this `/folder1` which is currently private. All files within this bucket are also private. I'm wondering whether if I make `/folder1` public, are only the files currently within the folder public at the time that I execute 'make public' or are any files added to this folder afterwards also then public? I'm trying to determine whether I must reselect the folder again after adding some files to it and then run 'make public' on `/folder1` all over again, and if this is the case, how I can automatically set this property.

Comment: There is no concept of using "Make Public" on a directory. You can use "Make Public" on individual objects, or you can create a Bucket Policy to make a directory public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you are referring to making objects publicly-readable via S3 bucket policy.

When you apply the policy is immaterial. The policy is evaluated at the time that an S3 request for an object is made. It's not applied just to those objects that match the policy at the time that you apply the policy.

Answer (score 1):

By default public access is not granted. In order to allow you should grant public read access manually or set public access policy to objects. Please read through the documentation on how to do that
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket/

You can also set it through I am account Settings.